# Sum of two random variables: trying to figure out book solution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Okay, so I am trying to solve an exercise in my book :
It says in simple words:
Calculate the probabillity $$P(X+Y \geq 500) \text{ where X, Y are independent random variables, exponentially distirbuted with parameter }\\ \lambda = 0.005 \text{. Also X, Y take  non-negative values}$$ .

I worked as such :
[image]

From the graph , we can get :
$$ 0 \leq X \leq 500 $$ and $$ 0 \leq Y \leq 500-x$$
$$P(X+Y \geq 500) = 1 - P(X+Y \leq 500) =  1 - P(Y \leq 500-x) = 1 - \int_{0}^{500}\int_{0}^{500-x} \lambda \lambda e^{-(x+y)} \approx 1 - 0.278 \approx 0.722$$
**The writer in the back of the book has : 0.278 (the compliment probabillity ) why is that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is well-known that the sum of $n$ $\text{Exponential}$ random variables with rate $\lambda$ is a $\text{Gamma}(n, \lambda)$ random variable (see here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/371768/distribution-of-sum-of-exponentials).

Therefore, the probability density function of $S = X + Y $ is
$$f_S(s) = \lambda^2se^{-\lambda s}\mathbf{1}_{[0, +\infty)}$$
where $\mathbf{1}_{[0, +\infty)}$ denotes the characteristic function over the interval $[0, +\infty)$.

Then, the probability you are looking for is
$$\int_{500}^{\infty} f_S(s) \;\text{d}s= \int_{500}^{\infty} \lambda^2se^{-\lambda s}\;\text{d}s = (500\lambda + 1)e^{-500\lambda}$$
and substituting the value $\lambda=0.005$ you get $0.278$.

Comment: is there a way to work it out without gamma? by the knowledge of fxy(x,y)?

Comment: Yes, you can use convolution. Check http://www.milefoot.com/math/stat/rv-sums.htm#:~:text=PDF%20of%20a%20Sum,that%20z%3Dx%2By.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you calculated $$P(X+Y\leq 500), $$ the complement of which you calculated.

Comment: i am confused could you elaborate